# How to add `*` in A-Z text

Tags: javascript, regex, string, replace, addition

*This is my string*

***String:*** `a+b=ab+bc+cajddndndmdmndndnd/10` .I need to add `*` in each alphabet is `>1` length .I need a result like below

***need:*** `a+b=a*b+b*c+c*a*j*d*d*n*d*n*d*m*d*m*n*d*n*d*n*d/10`

***snippet:***

```js
var data = 'a+b=ab+bc+cajddndndmdmndndnd/10'.
replace(/[a-z]{2}/g , (a,b,c) => {return a.replace(/([a-z]){1}/g,'*')})
console.log(data)
```

Not getting perfect anyone help me..!

Comment: Should letters left from the `=` also be affected?

Comment: I can't figure out what so bad in this question. Why downvotes?

Comment: @Xufox yes .its also .only length of alphabet `>1`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use a positive look ahead and replace.

```
([a-z])(?=[a-z])
```

Replace with `$1*`

```
str.replace(/([a-z])(?=[a-z])/g, "$1*")
```

Demo:

https://regex101.com/r/JBPpqG/1

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew I'm so bad at JS.

Comment: Actually, `str.replace(/([a-z])(?=[a-z])/g, "$1*")` works.